# How would i make an element inside of a div rotate repeatedly?

Tags: css, animation

I have a `div` and can neither use `ID` nor `class`.

I can only use `names` like so:

```
<div name="picture">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/p0Fu5UZ.jpg" />
</div>
<div name="info">
    <p>- Insert information here</p>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
div{
    -webkit-animation: name 4s infinite linear
}
@-webkit-keyframes name {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
```

What's the appropriate way to select any particular `div`, because `[name=picture]` doesn't work with the crammed code nor the non-crammed code. What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It should work for you:

**CSS:**

```
div[name="picture"] {
    -webkit-animation: name 4s infinite linear
}
@-webkit-keyframes name {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div name="picture">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/p0Fu5UZ.jpg" />
</div>
<div name="info">
    <p>- Insert information here</p>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/srnug/121/

If you need the elements inside the div to rotate, then you can modify the selector as `div[name="picture"] img` or `div[name="picture"] p`

Comment: :o thank you, the div[name="picture] is just what i needed.